# Child div as viewport for scrollable parent?

Tags: css

This might explain my question a bit better:

I need one child div positioned on top of the other so that the last-child is only showing around the edges, but the two child divs need to scroll together and keep the background of the first-child div static. This mesa that the viewport would be the first-child, but the content of the first and second child would have to scroll within the container so they can scroll together., with the first-child being the viewport.

---

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="row">Row</div>
        <div class="row">Row</div>
        <div class="row">Row</div>
        <div class="row">Row</div>
        <div class="row">Row</div>
        <div class="row">Row</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bars">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="a"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `bars` extend to the width of the page, and the `text` div is overlaid on top of them, with a margin around it. I position each `bars` div so that they match up at the same horizontal level with the visually corresponding `row`.

The `text` div is positioned to be `x` pixels from each side, so that there is a margin around it. This way, you can see the ends of the `bars` below it.

The markup is easy, but I can't figure out the CSS for this...

`text` is positioned absolutely, so that it can extend to the bounds of the page with a margin. This is fine if the content inside it stays within the bounds, but it does not in this case.

**This is all very hard to explain, but basically, here's the problem**: I set `container` to `overflow:scroll` because I need the `bars` to scroll with the `rows`. Since `text` has a background image, and is positioned so that you can just see the ends of the `rows` beneath it, it has to be `position:absolute`. This doesn't work, however, when the content exceeds the bounds of `text. I can't add the background image to`container`because it would cover the ends of the`bars`.

Does that make sense? No? Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/BskaP/2/

Does it still not make sense? Here's a picture:

[image]

Any ideas? Ask me some questions so I can explain this better.

Comment: so your problem is essentially that if you put a long piece of text in  a `row` it extends beyond the gray thing it is supposed to be inside of?

Comment: What's `the gray thing`?

Comment: the gray thing is the gray area surrounding the text

Comment: No. I want `.text` to be the viewport, meaning that everything within those bounds scrolls with it, but the scrollable area needs to be `.container` because I need `text` to scroll with `bars`.

Comment: could you possibly add a border to each `row` that looks like a `bar` but really isn't? see this: http://jsfiddle.net/BskaP/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a lot of the css that's there -- for example the .container. If I understand correctly (and I'm not 100% sure I do) you'd like a image on the .text div which remains fixed while the rest of the page -- bars and text scroll.

You cannot put the image on the text div as it will scroll; rather, I suggest putting the image on each .row with a `position: fixed` as well as using `padding-bottom:20px` instead of the margin, so that there appears to be an image behind all of the rows and the effect is continuous. That will give you the effect I think you're after

http://jsfiddle.net/BskaP/5/

Comment: Here's the thing. I need the div that has the scrollable content in it to be static height. In this case, however, `.text` doesn't retain a fixed height.

Comment: Actually, I got it figured out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `scrollTop()` function to get an elements position based on scroll. Coupled with a `scroll()` event, you should be able to sort something out.

So put something in your `scroll` event to offset the position of your rows and text by the value of `scrollTop()`.

`scrollTop()` : http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

`scroll` event : http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

My initial thoughts was to avoid JavaScript by combining the `rows` and `text` elements together and *fake* the rows being behind the text... but given your specific situation I couldn't come up with anything...

Comment: i don't know if he wants jquery

Comment: did you downvote me because "you don't know if he wants jQuery"? You also don't know that he doesn't want it either... it wasn't specified...

Comment: Could you post an example. I don't want to use jQuery, because I know there has to be a way to do this in CSS, but a working example of *something* is better than nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You should add `overflow:auto` to `row`. Here is a jsfiddle that proves it works: http://jsfiddle.net/BskaP/3/
I added an extra long row to it for an example.
I don't know if this is what you want, but I think it is.

Comment: `.text` should be the viewport, but `.container` should do the scrolling.

Comment: so how do you want the text to look if it is too big?